# Receiving broadcast error for Bluetooth discovery - Error in onReceive() method that receives intents by startDiscovery() Method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I am facing a problem in device scan activity. I want to `scan` all `bluetooth devices` in vicinity and print them on UI. But i am getting the same run time error as in [Receiving broadcast error for Bluetooth discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376388/receiving-broadcast-error-for-bluetooth-discovery).

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1000;
    public ArrayList<String> deviceArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Toast.makeText(this, "Device Doesn't Support Bluetooth!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
        }
        scanStart();
    }

    public void scanStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Adding Paired Devices into ArrayList
        addPairedDevices();

        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() == true){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Searching...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Adapter got Null Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(requestReciever, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy  

        try {
            Thread.sleep(12000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Printing Device List on UI
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.print_device_list, deviceArrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        setContentView(lv);
        if(deviceArrayList.size()<=0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Devices Found...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    public void addPairedDevices() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // get paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                deviceArrayList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress() + "\n" + device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                deviceList.add(device);
            }
        }
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver requestReciever = new BroadcastReceiver(){

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent == null) {
                return;
            }
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                Log.d("BT", "Device Found");
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(device!=null){
                    if(device.getName() != null && device.getName().length() > 0){
                        deviceArrayList.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress()+"\n"+device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                        deviceList.add(device);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    };


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Uesr Doesn't want to switch on Bluetooth!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter != null){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        if(requestReciever!=null)
            unregisterReceiver(requestReciever);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth App Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: post your error log here.

Comment: Thanx For Reply... Error Log is same as this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376388/receiving-broadcast-error-for-bluetooth-discovery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`device.getUuids()` - here you have a Null, that is why you have an error here.
Check this variable beforе using it.